# Purpose of qmldir file

Tags: qt, qml

I am having hard time understanding the prupose of the qmldir file. 
Based on the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html), qmldir is used to define a module and types. However, why do I need it for local Qml documents? I see many repositories ([example](https://github.com/obeezzy/FlatUI)) add qmldir for the project, while all the Qml documents are in the same directory. My understanding is that you need the qmldir only for modules. What I am missing here?

Comment: because that is a module that you have to install, but for you to be attaching it to your project, you could indicate how you are using those "files"

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "attaching files to your project"?

Comment: My simple question is: how are you using that library?